# WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process only with Apache

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, apache2

If I run the application using

> python manage.py runserver

the following code launch firefox

```html
driver =webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary, firefox_options=firefoxOptions,log_path='/home/projcts/geckodriver.log')
```

but if I wanted to use Apache the application run without any problem except that it doesn't launch firefox browser.
Is it a problem of permissions? or selenium doesn't work with apache?
I will appreciate any suggestions

Comment: why do you run it with Apache ? Do you run it on local computer ? if you run it on server then Selenium will not run Firefox on your local computer but on server using monitor connected to server - so you can't see it. Better use `print()` or log to save some information to see if it runs without error.

Comment: I am using apache to deploy my application. I run it on a server and on the server I can see it if I run it using python manage.py runserver but using apache I can't (always on the server)

Comment: apache usually runs as service so it runs as different user, with different privilages and without access to desktop so it can't display anything - all for security reason. Usually we need browser window only to write code and later window is not needed. We even use option `headless` so browser doesn't open window and it run faster.